# How to make xml file for side faces in face detection

Tags: java, c++, matlab, opencv, face-detection

I have been working on face detection and i am able to detect frontal faces like all other people using the haarcascade xml files. My next task is to detect a side face (Non-Frontal). I am working in opencv. The profileface xml is not able to detect the side faces with accuracy. So i feel only option left is to make my own xml file which can detect side faces. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to combine the frontal and profile face recognition?
I was working with this as well, and the result was pretty good actually.

You also need to specify the min and max framesize as accurate as possible.

Unfortunately I did not find a side face haarcascade, so it looks like, you need to train your own one.

if you just want to test this out, you don't actually need so many pictures of faces.
You need a lot of negatives. Because opencv provides a function to generate positive pictures based on a single image of the face and a bunch of negative pictures.

To find the negative pictures you could simply take a video of the backgrounds where you want to detect the faces, and then just extract all the images form the video file. From only 3 minutes you get over 2000 images.

For the training I would recommend you to keep the size of all pictures very small, because otherwise it will take like forever to train the cascade file.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can see opencv Cascade Classifier Training for a reference. I didn't try it, but offer you for a reference.

website: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html

---

and there are some Q&A for training.

website: http://www.computer-vision-software.com/blog/2009/11/faq-opencv-haartraining/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.